# Why was my "not an answer" flag declined? The "answer" amounts to "thanks"

Tags: discussion

[Here's the link to the answer in question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88810/what-is-the-query-to-display-the-failed-sql-jobs/143738#143738).

The first phrase is literally

> Thank you for the tip, this is exactly what I was looking for.

The second phrase contains a code fragment that does not answer the original question (which was about a query to display failed jobs). It provides an alternative way to calculate a variable, but in itself has no relevance to the question.

To me it looks very much like a "thank you" comment. Taken as a whole it does not even attempt to answer the original question. The suggested code piece could have been an edit to the other answer, to which the author supposedly refers.

Comment: The suggestion makes it much more than just a "thank you" comment, but I admit that if I wanted to make that suggestion, I'd make it a comment. You can see, though, that the author doesn't have enough reputation for a comment, and yet their suggestion adds value. My personal opinion is that the added value is enough to warrant an answer, particularly taking into account the author's inability to comment.

Comment: @AndriyM I think the criterium should be, does the post, in its entirety, provide an actual answer to the original question. In this case clearly no, it does not provide an answer to the original question, hence it's not an answer. Author's reputation or inability to comment should be irrelevant.

Comment: Code piece or cod piece?

Comment: @ButtleButkus -- you a Newfie?

Comment: Does one receive notifications like that? I've flagged a few posts (vast majority for the offensive/spam category), but a few in others. I've never been told that a flag has been declined - does that mean that my flags have been generally accepted? I've had comments deleted in the past,but I was never informed of that - I just revisited posts and noticed that stuff was missing. I think that we should be told that our contributions have been removed (with the reason) so that we can a) either learn from the experience or b) stand our ground and be able to defend our point!

Comment: @Vérace The notification showed up when I tried to flag another post later on; it said something like "your previous flag was declined; watch what you're doing".

Comment: "Big brother is watching you!". Maybe we should form the dba.stackexchange "underground"? Seriously though, it's probably all (mostly)'algorithmic (I hope... gulp...)... :-)

Comment: @Vérace you can the history of all your flags and what happened to them: [Verace flags](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/34007)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes sorry it looked like an attempt to answer when I processed your flag. It should have been deleted or converted to a comment instead. I have done that now. Apologies.

Comment: No worries, just trying to figure out if I misunderstood the flagging guidelines.